# how to set flink statsd reporter?

Tags: apache-flink

I read the doc and it can't work well,

I set the conf/flink-conf.yaml like that:

```
metrics.reporters: StatsDReporter
metrics.reporter.StatsDReporter.class: org.apache.flink.metrics.statsd.StatsDReporter
metrics.reporter.StatsDReporter.host: www.example.com
metrics.reporter.StatsDReporter.port: 8125
```

but I don't know and can't get where to import the statsDReporter?

is there some example to set it?

Comment: the configuration looks correct. did you place the flinik-metrics-statsd jar into flink's /lib folder? in any case, it would be good to know whether you get any error message.

Comment: thanks a lot, you are right, I find I didn't place the flink-metrics-statsd jar in the lib folder:-)